# What does the "splendour of Israel" has been hurled down to earth mean?

Tags: lamentations

In Lamentations 2:1 it is written:

> How the Lord has covered the daughter of Zion with the cloud of his
>   anger! **He has hurled down the splendour of Israel from heaven to
>   earth**, he has not remembered his footstool in the day of his anger.

I want to establish the meaning of the 'splendour of Israel' in the context bolded above. 'Israel' has not been hurled down from Heaven to earth, but 'her splendour' has. What is the significance of this distinction and what does this splendour consist of?

One commentary<sup>1</sup> suggests the phrase 'from heaven to earth' is used to imply the "most extreme fall imaginable", but I struggle to accept this view in full as it is only the splendour of Israel on which the emphasis is placed.

<sub><sup>1</sup> A bible commentary for today, W. Osborne, Lamentations page 855, Editors: G.C.D. Howley, F.F. Bruce,  H.L. Ellison.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period immediately preceding the Babylonian Captivity marked the time when the "Shekinah" of the Lord hesitatingly departed from the temple in Jerusalem ([Ezek 10:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezek%2010:4&version=NASB), [Ezek 10:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezek%2010:18&version=NASB) and [Ezek 11:23](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezek%2011:23&version=NASB)).

This glory is what provided shade to the Israelites from the hot desert sun when they were in the wilderness (for 40 years after leaving Egypt). The same glory also provided them heat in the cold desert nights. The glory of the Lord ("Shekinah") thus provided them shade in the day (cloud) and heat in the night (pillar of fire). This glory was their protector and "head of state," who gave the Law. Moses was the mediator.

In this passage of Lamentations, this glory of the Lord is now the "cloud of anger" ([Lam 2:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lam%202:1&version=NASB)), which is also "like a burning fire" in Jacob ([Lam 2:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lam%202:2&version=NASB)). The location of the "Shekinah" was the Ark of the Covenant, which was the footstool for the Lord ([1 Chr 28:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Chr%2028:2&version=NASB) and [Ps 132:7](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ps%20132:7&version=NASB) -- i.e., the "Shekinah" reposed above the Ark. This footstool is now abandoned ([Lam 2:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lam%202:1&version=NASB)).

The "glory of Israel" which is now cast down to earth was the loss of this glory; that is, by departing the Temple, the "Shekinah" no longer provided his presence on earth so that the King of Judah ruled the Jewish people through of the theocratic government of the Lord. Therefore from this point forward there are no more Jewish kings who are anointed.... the last chapter of Lamentations states: "The crown has fallen from our head" ([Lam 5:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lam%205:16&version=NASB)). The reference is to [Jeremiah 13:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jer%2013:18&version=NASB), which describes the last king of Judah who sat on the throne, and who was "de-crowned" -

> [Jeremiah 13:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2013:18&version=NASB) (NASB)
>   Say to the king and the queen mother,
>   “Take a lowly seat,
>   For your beautiful crown
>   Has come down from your head.”

The glory of the king is cast down. That is, King Jehoiachin and the queen mother, Nehusta ([2 Ki 24:8](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Ki%2024:8&version=NASB)), were taken captive into Babylon ([Jer 29:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jer%2029:2&version=NASB)). What was worse, King Jehoiachin was cursed by the Lord that no descendent of his would ever prosper on the throne ruling in Judah ([Jer 22:24-28](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jer%2022:24-28&version=NASB) and [Jer 37:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jer%2037:1&version=NASB)). Gentiles from this point forward appoint Jewish leaders, who are in some cases assassinated by the Jewish people (e.g., Gedaliah in [Jer 41:2-3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jer%2041:2-3&version=NASB)). So we now see a "flip-flop."

In other words, the casting down of the glory of Israel is the "flip-flop" of representing the Lord through the visible theocratic kingdom on earth. Thus the glory is cast from heaven to earth. Please click [**here**](https://sites.google.com/site/flipflopeng28/home/3/FlipFlopEng4.jpg) for the illustration. The "glory" now comes from earth instead of from heaven.

> [Jeremiah 2:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%202:11&version=NASB) (NASB)
>   “Has a nation changed gods
>   When they were not gods?
>   But My people have changed their glory
>   For that which does not profit.

Thus the beasts of the earth replace the glory ("flip-flop").  Daniel will later describe during the Babylonian Captivity that these "beasts" are the gentile nations that now will trample the earth (to include the Promised Land). According to the "flip-flop" illustration, we also see the parallel to the Garden of Eden, where the glory of the man went "flip-flop." The man is the head of the wife, and therefore his head is the glory of the Lord ([1 Cor 11:7-9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Cor%2011:7-9&version=NASB)); when the woman disobeyed him in the Garden of Eden, his glory (or crown) was cast down to the animals (earth).

The image here is thus not the rejection of the Jewish people by the Lord, who made his irrevocable promises to Abraham and David. Instead, the imagery here is the "flip-flop" of glory, which is turned upside-down, and thus no longer comes from heaven, but is instead cast down to earth where the "animals" dwell. ***Thus the crown or glory of Israel  has fallen from heaven to earth.*** Thus the glory of the gentile nations now prevails and menaces the earth, which includes the Promised Land.

Comment: I would agree that the crown of Israel has been hurled from heaven to earth because Lam 1:1 says,'She who was queen among the provinces has now become a slave.But you have only answered half my question because in Lam 1:8 it says,'All who honoured her despise her,for they have seen her nakedness.'She has obviously been stripped of her clothing as well as her crown and the removal of this splendour reduces her royal standing to the humiliation of a naked slave held in captivity.What is Israel,the virgin daughter of Zion, clothed with that has also been hurled to earth?

Comment: @Bagpipes - The parallel continues from the Garden of Eden, when the man (Adam) and the woman were stripped of their glory and found themselves "naked." The clothing of glory that was lost in Israel was the "Shekinah." That is, Israel was covered, or clothed, with this glory, which (up until this time) is what protected Jerusalem from foreign conquest. This removal also meant the end of the visible theocratic kingdom on earth, and thus the Virgin Daughter of Zion is now on par with the kingdoms of this world, which are described as animals or "beasts," which now menace the Promised Land...

Comment: @Bagpipes - One more thought: in the context of this passage, the imagery of the "cloud by day and pillar of fire by night" is now changed to say "the fire that consumes Jacob" and the "cloud of wrath" enveloping the nation (Lam 2:1-2). In other words, the "clothing" is no longer an asset, but a liability. This clothing is the Glory of the Lord ("Shekinah"). Please focus on the parallel to the Garden of Eden, and even the Christian New Testament parallel of a hen "covering" her chicks with its wing [(Luke 13:34)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+13:34&version=NASB).

Comment: To help  with the interpretation i have been looking at Rev 12:1, A great and wondrous sign appeared in heaven:a woman clothed with the sun,with the moon under her feet and a crown of twelve stars on her head.I hope that you will agree that this woman represents Israel.You will see the "crown of twelve stars" (which we both agree is the crown that has been hurled to earth in lamentations,)and also you will see "The virgin daughter of Zion" about to give birth to the Jesus,note:(Virgin daughter.)The woman is clothed in the sun which leads me to think that the sun could be the "Shekinah"

Comment: ,continued...What is your thoughts on the sun and the shekinah being one?What i want to establish is this.Has the sun been hurled down to earth(womans clothing)...Or has the Shekinah been hurled down to earth (The Glory of God).

Comment: @Bagpipes - The imagery from Rev 12:1 is another direct parallel to the Hebrew Bible, which is the dream of Joseph (Gen 37:9-10), and therefore represents biological descendants of Israel (faithful remnant). In my own **opinion**, the organic body of Christ will be removed from the earth. From that point, a cadre of believers will be saved, who will be biological descendants of Abraham who are in Covenant relationship with the Lord, and therefore are light-bearers once again. Please click [**here**](http://goo.gl/vI86rP). That is, the New Covenant will continue into the Tribulation Period.

Comment: @Bagpipes - Also, please click [**here**](http://goo.gl/vcE1am). I will translate this to English soon, but the "mystery" of Gentiles and Jews in one body was NOT predicted in the OT (Eph 2:13-18). Thus when the organic body of Christ is removed from the earth, believers in the Tribulation (cadre of faithful remnant) will later be united into the Body of Christ in heaven at the Marriage Supper of the Lamb, when all believers of all times (outside the "mystery" period) will be united to the body of Christ. While on earth in the tribulation however, they will carry the glory of the New Covenant.

Comment: your information is helpful.So am i wrong in my thinking that the woman in Rev 12:1 is clothed in the  "Shekinah"?

Comment: You are right! The initial cadre of believers in the tribulation will be biological descendants of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob. Their bodies will house the Spirit of God (as prophesied in Jer 36:27), but they will not be organically united to the Body of Christ -- that whole concept was the "mystery" revealed to Paul (please click [**here**](http://goo.gl/DKYvjA)). They will be no different than us, other than they will not not be united to the Body of Christ, which was the original "mystery." So in the Tribulation, they will have the Spirit of the Lord in them, and therefore possess Shekinah.

Comment: Some good thoughts and reflections here (although I admit I'm not convinced by Joseph's closing extrapolation in his answer!), but it ought to be noted that "[Shekinah](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13537-shekinah)" is a *post-biblical* concept, and does not appear in the Bible itself. See also the [Jastrow entry](https://archive.org/stream/dictionaryoftarg02jastuoft#page/1572/mode/1up) (right-column, 4th entry). If the question is about what *tiph'eret* means in the context of Lamentations and **as lament in the 6th C. BC**, then "shekinah" isn't part of the solution.

Comment: The concept of "Shekinah" is *writ-large* in the Bible. The Hebrew verb **שָׁכַן** ("Sh'kan") means to dwell, or to tabernacle, and was used to refer to the Glory of the Lord dwelling among men (Ex 24:16, Ex 25:8, Ex 29:45-46, Ex 40:35, + over 50 other instances). In the Greek New Testament the verb is translated σκηνόω; thus the concept of "Sh'kan" (Shekinah), or "the tabernacle dwelling (of the Lord)" is found in John 1:14, where the Word from heaven dwells or "tabernacles among us" (σκηνόω) in allusion to the concept found in the Hebrew Bible. Ditto in Rev 21:3, Rev 7:15, and Rev 13:6.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "writ large"! Since you know Hebrew and Greek, you'll know that *not one of the verses you cite* contains "*šĕkînâ*"; [σκηνόω](http://j.mp/1dKom43) is a good Greek word, means "encamp", used by [Xenophon](http://goo.gl/PxGke0), etc. Did you check the links in my previous comment? (Jastrow was [out by a page](http://j.mp/1d5C3ue) - sorry! or see [image if easier](http://i.imgur.com/T9W4lb0.png).) It's like saying [ὁμοούσιος](http://orthodoxwiki.org/Homoousios) is "writ large": maybe, but it still isn't in the Bible! See also [anachronism](http://goo.gl/f1NKyF).

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of issues in this verse. It's one of those in which the overall import is abundantly clear, even while the details remain somewhat obscure.

First, the text of Lam 2:1 -

> אֵיכָה יָעִיב בְּאַפּוֹ
>   אֲדֹנָי אֶת־בַּת־צִיּוֹן
>   *ʾēkâ yāʿîb bĕʾappô / ʾădōnāy ʾet-bat-ṣīyyôn*
>   How he has beclouded in anger / the Lord,<sup>a</sup> Daughter Zion
>
> הִשְׁלִיךְ מִשָּׁמַיִם אֶרֶץ
>   **תִּפְאֶרֶת** יִשְׂרָאֵל
>   *hišlîk miššāmayim ʾereṣ / **tipʾeret** yiśraʾēl*
>   He has cast down from heaven earth[wards] / the **tiph’eret** of Israel
>
> וְלֹא־זָכַר הֲדֹם־רַגְלָי
>   בְּיוֹם אַפּוֹ
>   *wělōʾ-zākar hădōm-raglāy / bĕyôm ʾappô*
>   and took no notice<sup>b</sup> of his footstool / in the day of his anger.

<sup>a. This is in most printed Hebrew Bibles; many manuscripts read the Tetragram here.</sup>
<sup>b. literally, "did not remember"</sup>

#### Context

In all of the poems of Lamentations, the first verse sets to the tone for the poem to follow, and this is true also here in ch. 2. Notice here how "his anger (*ʾappô*) begins and ends the verse, and reappears in v. 22 at its conclusion. The whole of Lam. 2 is about the the nature and effects of the Lord's anger aginst Jerusalem (note vv. 6-10, which are wholly set within the city, and in vv. 13 and 18 Zion/Jerusalem is directly addressed).

#### *tiph’eret*

This is word in question, the middle of these three poetic lines.<sup>1</sup> In abstract form, the [lexical range of this word](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/802/mode/1up) (right-hand column, second full entry) covers mostly the following:

- beauty, as in jewlery and apparel (Isa 3:18; Ezek 16:17);
- glory, as an attribute, e.g. of crown (Prov 4:9) or name (Isa 63:14);
- fame or honour (Judges 4:9; Prov 17:6)
- or, in a negative sense, pride or arrogance (Isa 10:12).

The [*Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament*](http://www.brill.com/hebrew-and-aramaic-lexicon-old-testament-2-vol-set) (*HALOT*) simply glosses this phrase as "the adornment of Israel ", and adds by way of comment: "what this means in concrete terms is uncertain, perhaps Jerusalem, or perhaps the temple" (!). So, OP is not alone in spotting a difficulty here.

What is clear is that *tiph’eret* is some glorious attribute of Israel, at home in "heaven" ... but what that is explicitly remains obscure.

#### Assessment

**(1)** Typically with this kind of question, one looks in the first instance to the parallelism of the Hebrew poetry for a guide. Often -- not always -- a corresponding term in an adjacent line will require one or other possible meanings from its partner in its neigbhoring line. Here, the reference to "footstool" in the third line might offer some help. In the Psalms, this is a reference to the Temple (Ps 99:5; 132:7). In Isaiah 66:1, however, "footstool" is the earth itself, for heaven's divine throne (compare Isaiah 6:1-4). This might bring us, then, into a "temple" setting ... although *tiph’eret* itself does not regularly have this association.

**(2)** Often, the ancient versions provide a good guide to an earlier understanding (where they are not reduced to guessing themselves, that is). The pre-Christian Greek translation (Septuagint) translates this key phrase by [δόξασμα](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*d%3Aentry+group%3D98%3Aentry%3Ddo%2Fcasma) Ισραηλ (*doxasma Israel*), "glory(?) of Israel". It's hard to know how much help this translation gives. The authoritative Liddell-Scott lexicon (linked above) glosses it as if the meaning of the Greek word was to be wholly aligned with its Hebrew counterpart. This kind of transferance is certainly not unknown, but one wonders, then, why here (and in Isa 46:13, an analogous context) the tranlsator did not simply use the standard and widely used Greek equivalent, δόξα (*doxa*) "glory". IF the translator's choice is deliberate and thoughtful, then something like "reputation" would be in mind -- not a bad translation at all.

(The [Aramaic Targum](http://targuman.org/blog/targum-lamentations/tglam-in-english/) only gives "glory of Israel" at this point, so not adding much to our investigation.)

**(3)** Reverting to lexical range of the Hebrew, as an attribute,<sup>2</sup> *tiph’eret* adds lustre or brilliance to the thing it describes. What might that be here, for Israel? Robin Salters, in his [*Lamentations* commentary](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KJZW_F8va1sC),<sup>3</sup> suggests a [number of possibilities](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KJZW_F8va1sC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA111#v=onepage&q&f=false), including Israel's "boasting", or the city of Jerusalem itself, or (his own preference) "Israel's illustrious past" (p. 114).

Others hold out the possibility, given the connection of *tiph’eret* with "crown", that this could be a "metonym" (where the part represents the whole) for the king. Was the king in Jerusalem really pictured in "heaven", however, from which setting to be cast down?

**(4)** Older commentators can also offer insight, of course. Unfortunately, Rashi [opted not to comment on this term](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16458#showrashi=true) so we can't call on his wisdom. What he does say points to the violence and suddenness of the fall, not the nature of the thing cast down.

#### Concluding thoughts

Unfortunately, this exercise (at least my efforts towards it) are somewhat inconclusive. That the authoritative *HALOT* withholds judgment should counsel us not to be hasty in wanting to pin down what the poet of Lamentations 2 did not make concrete. Two options stand out, to my mind

Given the slightly unusual Septuagint (Greek) rendering, however, there is some merit in Salters' suggestion that it is the "reputation" of Israel which has been so dramatically cast down. As the poet will go on to say, the God of Israel has become an enemy (Lamentations 2:5). While most of the poem will depict this graphically in terms of the destruction of the holy city, the active neglect to which the Lord subjects his people (2:1c) finds its counterpart in tarnishing their reputation in thus severing (casting from heaven) the relationship between them. This would participate in the sense of  as a national attribute (e.g., [Deut 26:19](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=eng-NASB1995&v1=DT26_19&w2=bible&t2=heb_wlc&v2=DT26_19); [Jer 13:11](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=eng-NASB1995&v1=JR13_11&w2=bible&t2=heb_wlc&v2=JR13_11), cf. 33:9).

However (and on the other hand), when used as an attribute, *tiph’eret* can also rather generically describe jewels ([Isa 3.18](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=eng-NASB1995&v1=IS3_18&w2=bible&t2=heb_wlc&v2=IS3_18)), or the temple (as in #1 under "Assessment", above), or a divine attribute ([Psalm 71:8](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=eng-NASB1995&v1=PS71_8&w2=bible&t2=heb_wlc&v2=PS71_8); [1 Chron 29:11](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=eng-NASB1995&v1=R129_11&w2=bible&t2=heb_wlc&v2=R129_11)), or (fairly often) a crown (e.g., [Prov 4:9](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=eng-NASB1995&v1=PR4_9&w2=bible&t2=heb_wlc&v2=PR4_9); [Ezek 23:42](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=eng-NASB1995&v1=EK23_42&w2=bible&t2=heb_wlc&v2=EK23_42); + several more). Given the parallelism with "footstool", the notion of *tiph’eret* suggesting a "crown" (i.e., cast down from "head to foot", in its entirety), is also appealing.

This is, however, one of those occasions where the poetic, metaphorical, and evocative language of the Bible resists the pedantic precision we as modern readers sometimes crave.

---

*NOTES*

1. It's a good opportunity, too, to see the poet's characteristic *qinah*, or dirge/lament meter: notice how each line has a 3:2 pattern. If the line is abstracted as A/B, then A has three stress units, and B has two.
2. Rather than "free-standing" as in the "fame"/"pride" nuances noted above.
3. R. Salters, *Lamentations: A Critical and Exegetical Commentary* (International Critical Commentary; London: T & T Clark, 2010). For some reason, the next link to the precise page works in Chrome, but not Firefox...

Comment: In the section Headed 'Assessment'(3) 2nd paragraph,you ask,"Was the King in Jerusalem really pictured in heaven,however, from which setting to be cast down?In Lam1:1 with reference to Israel (Jerusalem) the scripture says, "She who was Queen among the provinces,has now become a slave." sorry! but i am not understanding why you mention 'King' and not 'Queen.'

Comment: @Bagpipes Wherever you see "she" in Lam (I might need to nuance this!), it's referring to Jerusalem/Zion: cities are "feminine" in biblical Hebrew language and thought. On "king", I'm reporting what commentators (esp. [Provan, *Lamentations*, p. 59](http://j.mp/1mOOno0) have suggested. **If** *tiph’eret* is used here with reference to "crown" in metonymy for royalty, it would refer to kings (compare Joseph's reference to Lam 5:16). ¶ My growing sense is, though one wants to have some clarity here, *most* commentators I've checked are tentative, reluctant to be definite on *tiph’eret*!

Comment: Ezekiel 16:8-14 would appear to 'shed some light.'

Comment: @Bagpipes : Exactly - see Ezek 16:2 - "Son of man, make known to **Jerusalem** her abominations,..."

Comment: Yes, Ezekiel does speak the language!Because my question concerns a "heaven and earth" scene, i find my thoughts always go forward to Rev:12-1, and i wonder,does the sign point back to Lamentations,or is it just my imagination?

Comment: @Bagpipes I'm not aware of any find in Rev 12:1 an allusion to Lam 2:1 (although I'm hardly in a position to know for sure!). Lam 2:1 and Matt 5:35 *have* been linked, though. Revelation 12 is a special case: see the 154-page book by Pierre Prigent, *[Apocalypse 12: Histoire de l'exégèse](http://j.mp/1b2aDWt)* (1959) on the history of interpretation of this chapter alone. If your French is up to it, you can read a [fairly full review of it](http://j.mp/1hFUeeC) online. This is quite a different question from the one you posed (on "splendour" in Lam 2:1), though! Is this your "real" interest?

Comment: The language used in Rev:12,especially to describe Satan being "thrown out" of heaven," is similar to the language used to describe the "splendour of Israel" being "hurled from heaven to earth...Rev12:9 "Satan,who leads the whole world astray.He was hurled to earth and his angels with him."When the focus is on the Woman alone(not child birth) in Rev 12:1,I am sure you will agree that the woman could represent "The splendour of Israel" by way of the Crown of twelve stars.In short,In lamentations we view Israel as a "naked slave" and in Revelation we view Israel restored to her former glory....

Comment: Continued.... Because of the scriptures taken from Jeremiah and added to the Revelation of John,i feel it is fair to say that Rev:12-1 "weighs heavily" as being an allusion to Lam 2:1.-....I am going to try and get the book on revelation you mention-In English.

Comment: @Bagpipes Maybe, but you might be the first one ever to do so. :) Remember, things often look different in the original languages, and other connections may have more explanatory power. Really, 12:4 is where you should be looking, and the parallels between Lam 2:1 and Rev 12:4 are not close; note too 12:3 = "another [as in 'different'] sign". One of the [most comprehensive lists of OT-in-NT ever](http://goo.gl/0zC641) didn't spot it: you have to ask "why"! ([Read some background](http://goo.gl/4QYjIC) on that work, if you're interested.) Need to be careful *which* dots are being connected.

Comment: I will look at the info you have provided.I rest my case.

Answer (score 5):

According to Rabbinic tradition, found in a Midrash (Eicha Rabbosi 2,2):

> It is analogous to the inhabitants of a kingdom who made a crown for the king; they kept provoking and angering the king and, yet, he tolerated them; finally, the king said to them that seeing as he tolerates their provocations only because of the crown they fashioned on his behalf, “here is your gift tossed back in your faces”; so, too, did the Holy One say to Yisroel, “I only tolerate your provocations due to the glorious image of Yaakov that is engraved upon my Throne, here it is tossed back in your faces,” as it is written: “He cast down from heaven to earth the glory of Yisroel.'

So, in this context the term "Glory" or "Splendor" of Israel (תפארת ישראל) refers to the Image of Jacob that existed in Heaven wearing a crown (תפארת also means "crown").  Because of Jacob's merit, G-d could not destroy the Temple as long as the crowned image of Jacob remained there.  Accordingly, G-d first through down the crown of Jacob, freeing Him to destroy the Temple (i.e. the "footstool of G-d").

The Rabbis would not have said that the Children of Israel's entire merit was cast off because that would be contrary to  [Lev.  26:44-45](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9927), where G-d promises that no matter how great Israel's iniquity "*I will not reject them, neither will I abhor them, to destroy them utterly, and to break My covenant with them; for I am Hashem their G-d.  But I will for their sakes rememberthe covenant of their ancestors, whom I brought forth out of the land of Egypt in plain sight of the nations, that I might be their G-d; I am Hashem*."

Comment: This is very interesting! Has your answer in any way been influenced by the sun, moon and stars we read about in Genesis:37-9.?

Comment: @Bagpipes -- I don't see the connection, so I'm pretty sure it didn't influence me.

Answer (score 0):

The word [splendor](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/tiferet_8597.htm) (תִּפְאֶ֖רֶת tip̄·’e·reṯ) meaning excellence, glory, and beauty.

When we think about he BEST indicator of Israel's Glory, we think about the stars in heaven. The [oath](http://biblehub.com/genesis/26-4.htm) God made to Abraham. The second best indicator at that time, it would be The Temple. Thus the shift from heaven to earth in Lamentations. It is as if God burst out their bubble. The bubble being the stars in heaven. The idea of Israel's Glory, the stars in heaven, the oath. It is possible to see Israel's focus more on the Temple as they struggle to rebuilt it and lack of Joy as when rebuilt it. Wanting a Human King more than a God in Heaven.

In General, Lamentations 2:1, is like a figure of speech, burst someone's bubble.

Comment: Your input is appreciated.